# Beautiful soup appending

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I don't understand why this is not working.

```
soup_main = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a>FooBar</a></body></html>')
soup_append = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a>Meh</a></body></html>')
soup_main.body.append(soup_append.a)
```

I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 378, in append
self.insert(len(self.contents), tag)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 312, in insert
raise ValueError("Cannot insert None into a tag.")
ValueError: Cannot insert None into a tag.
```

I would be glad if I can understand what is happening.

Comment: I copied your code, and it's working (Proof: [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TastyEnlightenedNumericalanalysis)). Are you sure you've pasted the same code and HTML here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup_main = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a>FooBar</a></body></html>', 'html.parser')
soup_append = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body><a>Meh</a></body></html>', 'html.parser')
soup_main.body.append(soup_append.a)
print(soup_main)
```

Outputs:

```
<html><head></head><body><a>FooBar</a><a>Meh</a></body></html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I missed the 'html.parser' but the problem is I want to do it recursively. So if I try to add it again it fails. soup_main.body.append(soup_append.a) this fails.

Comment: That is because when you append the first time, `soup_append.a` becomes `None`. Check this value after the first append.

Comment: That helped me debug. I have what I want now. Thanks.